# I made a Model then linked it and saved it and now I cant unlink it

Tags: modeling

I made a model and I linked it all Together and saved it all, and now I need to unlink A model from that linked model but I cant. please help

Comment: How exactly did you "link it all together"? We need more details and possibly to see your Blend file before we can give you any advice. You can include images in your post by following [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) instructions and share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page if it isn't too large.

Comment: Hi, Thomas, and welcome to BSE. Your terminology is a bit ambiguous here, so this can't be reasonably answered without clarification. @JohnEason has made some good suggestions to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

If by "link" you mean "join" and by "unlink" you mean "separate", you can enter edit mode, select the parts you want to separate, hit *p* for the *separate* menu and click *selection*.

Comment: Thank you very Much!

Comment: @Thomas Gill If the answer is correct please mark it as so (chick icon)